# jQuery Autocomplete path bash style

Tags: jquery, bash, autocomplete, path

I'm developing an application using PHP and jQuery in which an input must take a file path on the server. The path is not trivial and there may be a lot of entries so I'd like to implement an auto complete field that behaves like bash, i.e. the suggestions list directories for the current level.

Say I have these directories available

```
    /a/001
    /a/002
    /a/003
    /b/020
    /b/021
    /c/002
```

To begin with, the auto complete should suggest a, b and c.
Then after entering a/ it should suggest 001, 002 and 003 ...

I think the server should build a tree of all available directories, write it as a js object, then the auto complete function should parse the input, tokenize on slashes / and locate the available sub directories in the corresponding node, and when a selection is made, append it to the current path.

---

**Update**

I'm almost there using the [jQuery Autocomplete w/ multiple values](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/multiple.html), but I don't like how it behaves. I wish the search action would fill in the text up to the next abiguity from what is available, just like bash's autocomplete does.

Here is what I have right now [link on pastbin](http://pastebin.com/Yvk9PzsH)

Comment: I just noticed, google's seach does exactly what I want...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got it as I imagined. The server builds a json tree which is dynamically parsed by the source function and using 2 input fields to populate a suggestion for the tab completion.

Put up a working [example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vanista/DJ4qn/13/)

```
function acSource(request, response) {
  var path = split(request.term);
  var depth = path.length;
  var node = paths;
  var avail = new Array();

  // descent into the path tree to get a list of suggestions
  for (var n = 1; n < depth && typeof node !== "undefined"; n++) {
    var cur = path[n - 1];
    node = node[cur];
  }

  // build a regex with the last directory entry being typed
  var last = path.pop();
  var re = new RegExp("^" + last + ".*", "i");

  // filter suggestions by matching with the regex
  for (var k in node) {
    if (k.match(re)) avail.push(k);
  }

  // build a new suggestion
  path.push(sharedStart(avail));
  if (avail.length == 1) path.push("");

  // set suggestion for autocomplete
  var sugg = $(this.element).siblings(".pathSuggest");
  $(sugg).val(path.join("/"));

  // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
  response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(avail, last));
}
```

Comment: I took this code and converted it to a jquery plugin. The format for usage is $(".path.input").pathAutocomplete(paths). There is a sample running at http://wholcomb.github.io/path-autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with the following, this solution will work for you. It is too simple

1. Show the suggestions as full paths. ie if the user types **/a/**
   then show suggestions for **/a/001, /a/002 and /a/003** instead of
   **001, 002 and 003**

In this case you can create [jQuery autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) with remote data-source

```
$("#birds").autocomplete({
    source: "search.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        log(ui.item ? "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
    }
});
```

Then in `search.php` you can generate required values as a json array.

Else you can create a custom auto complete which shows only the partial paths on server.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to avoid giving the full path as it may be cluttered. The directory tree I want to browse is made up of three levels and each one can have lots of entries.

As an alternative I was thinking about using select boxes for each depth which are dynamically loaded with the appropriate directory listing.

Comment: If you are sure of three levels, then you can use three jQuery autocompletes. Loading json and all will be managed by jQuery. So it will be simple for you.